# The update does not apply

Tags: java, mysql

The update does not apply when i try to change the variable while running the program. It does not have any errors.
It says the update is recorded successfully but it does not apply to Mysql.
Please help!

StaffDA

```
 public void actionPerformedUpdate() {
  if (StaffDA.updateCustomer(customer)) {
    txtfName.setEditable(false);
    txtlName.setEditable(false);
    txtGender.setEditable(false);
    txtEmail.setEditable(false);
    txtDateOfBirth.setEditable(false);
    txtUserId.setEditable(false);
    txtPassword.setEditable(false);
    txtContactNumber.setEditable(false);
    txtAddress.setEditable(false);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,
                    "Record updated successfully", "Alert",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,
                        "Database Error. Record not updated.", "Alert",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
```

StaffUpdatePanel

```
    public static boolean updateCustomer(Customer customer) {
    //declare local variables
    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery; 
    PreparedStatement pstmt;

    //step 1 - establish connection to database
    db.getConnection();     

    //step 2 - declare the SQL statement
    dbQuery = "UPDATE customer SET fName = ?, lName = ?, gender = ?, email = ?, dateOfBirth = ?, userId = ?, password = ? ,contactNumber = ?, address = ? WHERE id = ?";
    pstmt = db.getPreparedStatement(dbQuery);

    //step 3 - to update record using executeUpdate method
    try {

        pstmt.setString(1, customer.getfName());
        pstmt.setString(2, customer.getlName());
        pstmt.setString(3, customer.getGender());
        pstmt.setString(4, customer.getEmail());
        pstmt.setString(5, customer.getDateOfBirth());
        pstmt.setString(6, customer.getUserId());
        pstmt.setString(7, customer.getPassword());
        pstmt.setString(8, customer.getContactNumber());
        pstmt.setString(9, customer.getAddress());
        pstmt.setInt(10, customer.getId());
        if (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1)
            success = true;
        pstmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(success);
    //step 4 - close connection
    db.terminate();

    return success;     
}
```

Comment: Is autocommit true or false? If false, you need to explicitly commit using `Connection.commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the database user's access rights to the database. If you can do a select statement on the database, you could have set the DB user to only have read access.

Also you could try to print out the update statement and run in manually on the database with the same user, to see if the database system itself can run the update correctly, in this case you have narrowed down the problem to the code and not access rights.